# I have 6 components in my angular 4 project to load at first time. Is there any way not to load all components at a time?

Tags: angular

All 6 components are 
 1. header,
 2. Topbanner
 3. WhytoUSe
 4. Slider
 5. WhatweDo
 6. Footer

Picture Link of my website:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pj3nZ.jpg

Many times user stick to the components 1 and 2. They don't scroll down. How can I manage if any user scrolls down then only rest of the components will be loaded?

Comment: I supouse you can use a variable "showMore" and a  @HostListener('scroll') onScroll(){ this.showMore=true  }. If your all rest component have an *ngIf="showMore", must be work

Comment: create a module for component you want to load lazy. and then load that module on scroll using `NgModuleFactoryLoader`.